# How to get the words after splitting characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read usernames by sending a cmd command

```
root = subprocess.check_output(
    "netsh wlan show profiles", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode()
```

Suppose i get below Output from the root cmd

```
sample root output  = ["All User Profile     : L",
            "All User Profile     : Sp",
            "All User Profile     : Pixel",
            "All User Profile     : Home",
            "All User Profile     : lph",
            "All User Profile     : lp"
            ]
```

Here i need to get the characters after **":"**  like **L,Sp etc** for this i am trying the below code but i am getting **"All User Profile"** how can i get the required OP

```
for x in list:
    if "User" in x:
        print(x.split(":", 1)[0])
```

if i do `print(x.split(":", 1)[1])` i am gtting list index out of range error

Answer (score 0):

Try with -1 in place of 0

```
for x in root.splitlines():
    if "User" in x:
        print(x.split(":",1)[-1])
```